# Let $d=(m,n)$, then for any $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $kd=mq+nr$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $d=(m,n)$, then for any $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ there is a $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $kd=mq+nr$

This is a small conjecture I believe to be true. On Group Theory class we were asked to calculate the subgroups $HK$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, were $H=mZ$ and $K=nZ$.
I decided to solve the problem by considering 3 cases:

1. ($m=nq$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$) or ($n=mt$ for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$)
2. $(m,n)$=1
3. None of the conditions on 1) is satisfied and $(m,n)>1$.

The case I'm stuck at is 3). I found it easy to prove that $d\mathbb{Z} \subset (n\mathbb{Z})(m\mathbb{Z})$. I struggle to prove that $(n\mathbb{Z})(m\mathbb{Z}) \subset d\mathbb{Z}$. In order to prove this last part I think my conjecture is key.

Is there any elementary result in Number Theory that I'm missing in order to prove this?

Comment: This is just a thought, but can you use Bézout's identity for this? The conjecture looks a lot like it.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: @Accelerator: looks like we had the same thought at the same time : )

Comment: @Accelerator you are absolutely right, it does help! I also used that $d$ divides both $m$ and $n$. So for any $nq$ and $mp$, $d$ divides $nq$ and $d$ divides $mp$.

Comment: By dupe: for *any* common divisor $\,\color{#c00}{d\mid m,n}\Rightarrow d\mid qm+rn,\,$ with quotient $\,k = q(\color{#c00}{m/d}) + r(\color{#c00}{n/d})$

Comment: @user1090793 Bezout is a red herring - it is true for *any* common divisor - see the prior comment.

Comment: @Accelerator See the prior comment.

Comment: @BillDubuque: duly noted. OP, note that Bill’s comment provides a more general and simpler answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $d = (m, n)$, we know $m = dx$ and $n = dy $, for some $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $mq + nr = (dx)q + (dy)r = d(xq + yr)$. Setting $xq + yr = k$, the result is proven.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).